# My cookie token is strong enough in order to use that for user authentication purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would know if the code that I am using in order to set the cookie value for user authentication purposes is strong enough.

In my model I have:

```
require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def make_cookie_id_salt(string)
    secure_hash("#{self.id}--#{string}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
cookies.signed[:current_user_id] = { :value => [@user.id, @user.make_cookie_id_salt(@user.id)], :expires => 15.days.from_now }
```

**Is it strong enough? If no, how I can improve that** (*make an example*!)**?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that gets put into cookies is stored as plain text.

If you set a cookie, and then check the cookies in your browser you will notice (in your case the cookie name would be current_user_id) that it is represented by a string of characters like:  G8gcm9sbCB5b3VyIG93biBhdXRoIHRvIGt... (Not quite plain text, right? It is actually Base64 encoded, but you can easily read it - require('base64'); Base64.decode64(string)).

Rails stores a special _yourapp_session cookie that is used to check the cookies validity. If for example someone/something was trying to modify it, it would get rejected.

Now in your case it doesn't really matter if you try to hash something in the cookie or not.
It is just used for authentication (to look up a user in the database by his id) and you are not storing any unique secret data (Which you should not place in a cookie anyway, but it would be the only reason to hash something)

Of course someone could steal the cookie of a user (if he used a public computer and hasn't cleared his cache, etc.) and log in, but there's no way to prevent that (No matter what kind of hashing was used to obfsucate it)

In conclusion you should be fine with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to create your own, I suggest using the Authlogic gem.  In a few minutes of configuration you get a complete authentication solution, including cookies and much more.  If you really want to roll your own, install the Authlogic gem and take a look at how they do it.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @user502052, while they might not have directly answered your question, they are telling you that it is better to use a well tested authentication solution than to roll your own. If you lack the expertise in authentication and try writing your own, and have to ask if you did it right, the odds are really good that you didn't. Your choice now is to ignore the answers given and run with your solution and find out whether you did it right and maybe suffer a hacked site if you didn't, or, look at alternate solutions and learn from them. It's your choice.

Comment: Where I can be wrong? I aim to make my application almost writing all the code (is it the right way?). I don't know, but I think it is better to have proprietary code, to be independent of other plugins and gems and to have a consistent and well know software. Why you should use the third-party code? P.S.: thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user502052, if you really believe that then you are completely and totally doomed in this field. Why are you using Rails, then? What's different about Devise vs Active-whatever that happens to be already integrated in Rails? Mongrel? Apache? WEBrick? If in fact you are just trying to learn and this is not a real application, you might have got an answer if you said that, it was by itself a good question. I upvoted it. The problem for real apps is that if 100 people write their own auth, that will mean 80 new hackable apps out there on the web. *That's* why not.

Answer (score 1):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is another option. It's extremely configurable, pretty DRY, with exhausting [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages).

For now-days I prefer it over Authlogic.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer the question.